# Swing getText won't read user input

Tags: java, swing

I've been trying to get the GUI going for the application I'm working on, and, it's been ages since doing anything in Swing. Most of the stuff has come back, but not this. I cannot understand why, across none of the different text components, if I type something into them, getText() will always return "" regardless. It'll return correctly if I use setText() as a test, but that's not really helpful.

This remains consistent across JTextArea/JTextField, various ways of referencing the text field (direct variable vs pulling from the HashMap), and regardless of what kind of thread does the accessing. At times I've used the debugger to try and look at things as they're happening through other test snippets, and still nothing. Since the edit, have trimmed a lot of these cases out, but still persists in the problem.

In all cases, user input is never acquired.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class LifePathUI2 {

     final static boolean shouldWeightX = true;
     private GridBagConstraints cons;
     private BorderLayout windowLayout;
     private GridBagLayout layout;
     private JFrame mainWindow;
     private JPanel mainPanel;


     private JComponent currentComponent;
     private JTextField characterName;

    /**
     * @throws HeadlessException
     */
    public LifePathUI2() throws HeadlessException {
        cons = new GridBagConstraints();
        windowLayout = new BorderLayout();
        layout = new GridBagLayout();
        mainWindow = new JFrame();     
        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        init();
    }


    public void init()
    {
        mainWindow.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

        mainWindow.setLayout(windowLayout);


        cons.ipadx = 5;
        cons.ipady = 5;
        cons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        cons.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        cons.weighty = 1.0;
        cons.weightx = 1.0;

        // to make everything work right we add a mainPanel under the mainWindow
        cons.gridheight = 1;
        cons.gridwidth = 1;

        mainWindow.add(mainPanel);
        // Readers keep in mind if you don't set this below, strange behavior happens
        mainPanel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        mainPanel.setLayout(layout);

        currentComponent = mainPanel;

        addLabel(0,0,"Character Name");
        characterName = addTextF(1,0,"",30,true);
        endRow(2,0);

        addButton(0,1,"Foo").addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println(characterName.getText());
            }   
        });

        endVertical(0,2);

        mainWindow.setSize(1400, 900);

        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Inserts a spacer to signify the end of components for this row (effects layout so it doesn't center)
     */
    private void endRow(int x, int y)
    {
        cons.weightx = 100.0;
        addLabel(x,y,"");
        cons.weightx = 1.0;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts a spacer to signify the end of components vertically (effects layout so it doesn't center)
     */
    private void endVertical(int x, int y)
    { 
        cons.weighty = 100.0;
        addLabel(x,y,"");
        cons.weighty = 1.0;
    }

    /**
     * Shorthand command to add label at coordinates with text
     * @param x non-negative integer
     * @param y non-negative integer
     * @param text Display Text for label
     */
    private JLabel addLabel(int x, int y, String text)
    {
        JLabel temp = new JLabel(text);
        addC(temp,x,y);
        return temp;
    }

    /**
     * Shorthand command to add Button at coordinates with text
     * @param x non-negative integer
     * @param y non-negative integer
     * @param text Display Text for Button
     * @return The component created
     */
    private JButton addButton(int x, int y, String text)
    {
        JButton temp = new JButton(text);
        addC(temp,x,y);
        return temp;
    }

    /**
     * Shorthand command to add Text Field at coordinates with text
     * @param x non-negative integer
     * @param y non-negative integer
     * @param value the default value for the text field
     * @param cols Number of Columns
     * @param updateListen If true will add listener that triggers UI updates when values change
     * @return The component created
     */
    private JTextField addTextF(int x, int y, String value, int cols, boolean updateListen)
    {
        JTextField temp = new JTextField(value, cols);

        // this prevents the common issue of the text fields turning into slits
        temp.setMinimumSize(temp.getPreferredSize());

        addC(temp,x,y);
        return temp;
    }

    /**
     * Shorthand to add new components to the UI tab at given coords
     * @param comp Component to add to UI
     * @param x non-negative integer
     * @param y non-negative integer
     * 
     */
    private void addC(JComponent comp, int x, int y) {
        cons.gridx = x;
        cons.gridy = y;
        currentComponent.add(comp,cons);
    }


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                LifePathUI2 ui = new LifePathUI2();
                ui.init();
            }
        }); 

    }

}
```

I've searched every question here for swing stuff and none of them problems seem to correspond to this problem specifically. Was not entirely expecting that.

I apologize for the bigger snippet but since all of the parts immediately around creating the text fields, reading them, creating the GUI itself, all seem to match the examples online I've seen... I'm just smart enough to know there must be something odd I did here and just not seeing it.

EDIT: Simplifying example. Despite breaking this down to a much more simple test case, still no dice
EDIT2: Finished compression of things. I was actually expecting this to work because this is on the level of working code I've written before. But still nothing

Comment: `I cannot understand why, across none of the different text components, if I type something into them, getText() will always return ""` - this is likely because you created two components and your code is referencing a component that is NOT displayed in the frame so you get null. Start by creating a simple frame with a text field and a button. When you click the button you display the text. Prove to yourself that the simple case works. Then determine why you have two components. You posted too much code for me to look at.

Comment: try temp.setText(getTextF(name));   you will have to make sure you pass string..

Comment: You've much too much cyclomatic complexity in your code, and this is what is making it difficult for you to debug your code and for you to be able to post a **small** testable runnable program. You should refactor your code to simplify it such that you have smaller classes, ones that are testable in isolation (with appropriate mocking), as this will help both you and us now and in the future.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - if you see the fucntion getTextFVal(String name) which has the textfield temp, its not set with a text.. what do you think?

Comment: @BhavikPatel: I'm trying to pare down his code to a minimal form to understand what it's doing (something that he should be doing for us **before** posting), but it's still too convoluted.

Comment: I suspect that his `update()` method is bad. If he's trying to extract the text from a DocumentListener's Document, then he should get the Document object from the DocumentEvent parameter and work with it.

Comment: Reducing the example down to something that doesn't have to deal with nested panels or even doucmentlisteners. Is still blanking on me.

Comment: In a second going to ditch the HashMap and more of the helper functions as well.

Comment: You call `init()` ***TWICE***!!! That's it! That means that you create two of everything, one displayed and one not. Adding to my answer below. See edit to answer. 1+ for simplifying your question which allowed me to figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A wild guess, but your `update()` method looks like it *might* be trying to extract the text from the Document that its listening to (you don't say), and if so, then use the DocumentEvent to get the Document and then extract the text. Something like:

```
private class TextChangeListener implements DocumentListener {
  @Override
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
     update(e);
  }

  @Override
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
     update(e);
  }

  @Override
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
     update(e);
  }
}
```

and

```
private void update(DocumentEvent e) {
  String text;
  try {
     Document doc = e.getDocument();
     text = e.getDocument().getText(0, doc.getLength());
     // do something with text here! ************
     System.out.println(text);
  } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
     e1.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Other than that, I'm lost in your code. Simplify. Refactor. Simplify some more. Refactor some more. Think smaller classes that can be fully tested in isolation.

---

**Edit**

You call `init()` ***TWICE***, and that's the problem since it means that you create two of everything, one displayed and one not.

You first call it here:

```
public LifePathUI2() throws HeadlessException {
  // ....
  init();
}
```

and then call it again in your main:

```
  javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        LifePathUI2 ui = new LifePathUI2();
        ui.init();
     }
  });
```

Call it only **once**.

Change this:

```
public LifePathUI2() throws HeadlessException {
  cons = new GridBagConstraints();
  windowLayout = new BorderLayout();
  layout = new GridBagLayout();
  mainWindow = new JFrame();
  mainPanel = new JPanel();
  mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  init();
}
```

to this:

```
public LifePathUI2() throws HeadlessException {
  cons = new GridBagConstraints();
  windowLayout = new BorderLayout();
  layout = new GridBagLayout();
  mainWindow = new JFrame();
  mainPanel = new JPanel();
  mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  // init();
}
```

Comment: There it is! Thanks. I knew i had covered most of the contingencies from the comments based on other people's answers, but something like this is the thing I always miss...

Comment: @Vigilant: again, thanks for the simplification as it helped **greatly**.